# How to use attach actor to component

Tags: components, actor, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to make a hockey game in Unreal engine and trying to make a way for the puck to attach to the players stick when the stick enters the pucks HitBox. This is what I've tried but it is not working at all! (This blueprint is in the pucks event graph) pls help, new to ue4

[image]

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on a node in the picture, does it get hit?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're testing the overlap against the *ThirdPersonCharacter*'s collision mesh, which is just a capsule shape centred on the actor. In your BP, the *OnComponentBeginOverlap* event will only fire with *OtherActor* returning the character if the puck overlaps that capsule object. It would seem likely to me that the hockey puck never touches it, especially if the puck is sliding around on the floor.

You need to test against the hockey stick's own collision, for which you need to use the *OverlappedComponent* value and cast to the hockey stick class to test that it's a hockey stick. Or you need a separate collision mesh at the end of the hockey stick.

I don't know how your *ThirdPersonCharacter* is constructed so it's difficult to say.